# SSMS Hide Row Numbers Under Results

Tags: ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio, how do I hide these row numbers under the "Results" highlighted in green?

[image]

Note: These are not the "Line Numbers" in the text editor, these are the row numbers in the results.

Comment: I'll stand corrected if I'm wrong, but I don't believe you can hide those row numbers

Comment: Anyone know for sure? I've used other DB management apps where it's possible (Toad Data Point, for example).

Comment: Any particular reason why they're bugging you?  For me, if I'm doing anything more than just quickly checking some data, I will copy and past the grid results out to Excel for any further analysis or manipulation.  I really can't even think of a reason why you'd need those row numbers to go away ......

Comment: @Craig I'm used to seeing the Results view without the numbers. At my previous workplace, we used Toad Data Point, which provides the option to simply turn them off in the settings. I'm wondering if SSMS does too? I've look through the options but haven't been lucky.

Comment: Does anybody know?